# How use CSS3 selector for select h2

Tags: html, css

my code is:

```
<div id="page" class="clearfix">
  <div class="span12 row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span3">
        <h2 style="background: #aaa">Text 1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
        <h2 style="background: #bbb">Text 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="span3">
        <h2 style="background: #ccc">Text 3</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
        <h2 style="background: #ddd">Text 4</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need **background of h2** define using css3 selector. I try following:

```
.row .span3 h2:nth-of-type(1) {background: #aaa};
.row .span4 h2:nth-of-type(1) {background: #bbb};
.row .span3 h2:nth-of-type(2) {background: #ccc};
.row .span4 h2:nth-of-type(2) {background: #ddd};
```

and this not working.

Can I ask for help? Thanks

Comment: How many such styles do you have to apply? This might be very difficult (if not impossible) with `nth-of-type` because as Danield has pointed out above the `nth-of-type` does not work this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, lose the inline styles.

Then you shouldn't call the `nth-of-type` on the `h2`. Since there is only one `h2` in each parent (`.span*`) it will never have a second one.

Instead, you call it on the parent class. What you are actually looking for is a `nth-of-class` pseudo class, which doesn't exist.

To work around it in your code, you can use the [substring matching attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings), so it won't matter if the div's class is called `span1` or `span99`.

All together your code could look like this:

HTML

```
<div id="page" class="clearfix">
    <div class="span12 row">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
                 <h2>Text 1</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                 <h2>Text 2</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                 <h2>Text 3</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                 <h2>Text 4</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row [class^='span']:nth-of-type(1) h2 {background: #aaa;}
.row [class^='span']:nth-of-type(2) h2 {background: #bbb;}
.row [class^='span']:nth-of-type(3) h2 {background: #ccc;}
.row [class^='span']:nth-of-type(4) h2 {background: #ddd;}
```

Also check the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1erqg60v/4/)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Yes, you are absolutely right... I didn't properly read the code... I replaced the answer.

Comment: This would work provided the structure remains the same. But it would not if the structure were to be changed and the `.span4` was to come below the second `.span3`.

Comment: Yes, you are true. But ofcourse this answer fits the code that is provided. Other or changed code might need adjustment.

Answer (score 2):

> I need background of h2 define using css3 selector

Assuming the code which you have provided, this can be done with the '~' [General sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) [(Which is a css3 selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors#Specifications)) - Like so:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/g003o88r/1/)

```css
.row .span3 h2 {
  background: red;
}
.row .span4 h2 {
  background: blue;
}
.row .span3 ~ .span3 h2 {
  background: orange;
}
.row .span4 ~ .span4 h2 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="page" class="clearfix">
  <div class="span12 row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span3">
        <h2>Text 1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
        <h2>Text 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="span3">
        <h2>Text 3</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
        <h2>Text 4</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably the best option. But even this would have problems if say the OP needed the 3rd `.span3` to be styled even more differently.

Comment: @Harry , yes that's why I said:"Assuming the code which you have provided". If there are addittional `.span3 `and `.span4` elements - then you'd need to add an extra level of `~` selectors -   http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/g003o88r/3/

Comment: Absolutely agreed mate. I wasn't trying to degrade the answer but just wanted to make it clear to the OP and any future readers :)

Answer (score 0):

What I do see is that you define the background in inline elements.

```
<h2 style="background: #ddd">Text 4</h2>
```

This does have priority over your css stylesheet and therefore it isn't working.

Comment: Of course this works... but it isn't a nice solution (imo). It's much better to separate your styling from your structure. Meaning having .html files and separate .css files...

Comment: Indeed, it's better to seperate, but the original question has it's styles defined inline.

Answer (score 0):

Orr.. instead of doing what Complexity said for EVERY single h2 in your webpage.

You can just add this line to your CSS:

```
h2 {
   background-color: #000000;
   color: #123123; //You can change these properties to whatever you want.
}
```

Comment: I haven't said to add inline CSS, There is already inline CSS. See the original question and read my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div:nth-of-type(1)>h2 {background: red;}
div:nth-of-type(2)>h2 {background: blue;}
div:nth-of-type(3)>h2 {background: yellow;}
div:nth-of-type(4)>h2 {background: green;}
```

```html
<div id="page" class="clearfix">
  <div class="span12 row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span3">
        <h2>Text 1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
        <h2>Text 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="span3">
        <h2>Text 3</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
        <h2>Text 4</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```